# Recreate kibana widgets by directly querying elastic search instance

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have running application of ELK stack, where I am generating the visualizations using Kibana.

but, can I generate the visualizations similar to kibana widgets by directly querying my elastic

search instance and feeding the incoming data to `elastic charts`

Comment: Please check below my answer and marked as solution and upvote if it really helps you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can achieve it because Kibana Visualization generates based on [Elastic DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/query-dsl.html) and [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/search-aggregations.html).

You can view the query of specific visulization by following below steps:

1. Go to Kibana -> Visualize
2. Open the specific visulization which is created.
3. Click on Inspect on top right corner.
4. Select Request tab. Here, you will be able to see query generated by Kibana for creating chart.
5. You can copy request and execute using Elasticsearch instance and use response for showing Graph.

[image]

Comment: looks cool ! But, can I feed this data to elastic-chart and then get the visualization out of it ?

Comment: Honestly, I have never used elastic-chart so not sure but i think so after getting response and applying some transform logic you can pass data to chart.

Comment: Please check this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/charts/v/1.1.1) where they have given example of providing data as array. so you can call the elastic API and based on response you can convert to array and pass to elastic-chart.

Comment: does charts are generated on client side or server side ?

Comment: @code_thirsty it will generrate on client side because in API you will get data only and using data you can generate any type of charts.